# Error when gem push to Rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I try to create new gem from Rubygems guides and end my hola_ali gem and then try to push to Rubygems after enter my username and password I have this error

```
HTTP Basic: Access denied.
```

And I was make credentials file, Any idea to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing your command with "sudo"